# how to compare two optional NSArrays in Swift

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, swift

Let's have two optional NSArrays. The goal is to check, if they are equal. My solution is

```
func isArrayEqualToArray(array1:NSArray?, array2:NSArray?) -> Bool {

    let areBothEmpty:Bool = array1 == nil && array2 == nil

    var areBothEqual:Bool
    if !areBothEmpty && array2 != nil {
        areBothEqual = array1?.isEqualToArray(array2!) ?? false
    } else {
        areBothEqual = false
    }

    let result = areBothEqual || areBothEmpty
    return result
}
```

I feel that it is a little too verbose. It should be doable in a more concise and readable way. Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite simple:

```
func isArrayEqualToArray(array1: NSArray?, array2: NSArray?) -> Bool {
    return array1 == array2
}
```

does exactly what you want.

**Why does it work?** Here `==` is the operator that compares optionals

```
func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

and that gives `true` if both operands are `nil`, or of both 
operands are non-nil and the unwrapped operands are equal.

Also `NSArray` inherits from `NSObject` which conforms to `Equatable`,
and comparing `NSObject`s with `==` uses the `isEqual:` method, which is
implemented as `isEqualToArray:` on `NSArray`.
Therefore

```
array1 == array2
```

gives the same result as

```
array1.isEqualToArray(array2)
```

Comment: ... which is much nicer than in Objective-C where this kind of thing was a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed, you don't need to overcomplicate things:

```
func isArrayEqualToArray(array1: NSArray?, array2: NSArray?) -> Bool {
    if array1 == nil && array2 == nil {
        return true;
    }

    if array1 != nil && array2 != nil {
        return array1!.isEqualToArray(array2!);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `switch` statement may be clearer:

```
func isArrayEqualToArray(a1: NSArray?, a2: NSArray?) -> Bool {
    switch (a1,a2) {
        case (.Some(a1),.Some(a2)):
            return a1.isEqualToArray(a2)
        case (.None,.None):
            return true
        default:
            return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked @The Paramagnetic Croiss answer but I'm still going to shorten it a bit because I see that I can.

```

```
func isArrayEqualToArray(array1: NSArray?, array2: NSArray?) -> Bool {
    if array1 == array2 {
        return true;
    }
    if array1 != nil && array2 != nil {
        return array1!.isEqualToArray(array2!);
    }
    return false;
}
```

```