# NSFetchedResultsController XCode 7 issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

Xcode 7 beta 6 and and NSFetchedResultsController gave me headache today. If I compile same(with Swift 2 fixes) code with Xcode 6, program works on device and simulators(iOS 7, iOS8). However if I compile with Xcode 7 beta 6, program crashes on device(iOS 8.4) with following error messages whenever I update Core Data.

I get an error similar to below

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section
>   after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in
>   that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows
>   inserted or deleted from that section (2 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus
>   or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved
>   in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

Sometimes it crashes with another error like

> Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

```
//NSFetchedResultsController delegates



func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        return
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        print("Insert New: \(newIndexPath) Old: \(indexPath)")
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        print("Delete New: \(newIndexPath) Old: \(indexPath)")
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
        print("Update New: \(newIndexPath) Old: \(indexPath)")
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        //self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
    case .Move:
        print("Move New: \(newIndexPath) Old: \(indexPath)")
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

for the `.Update` section I also tried to call

```
 self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
```

Configure cell method:

```
func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 
   let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Person 
   //etc 
}
```

Sort Descriptors

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

Program always crashes. Only way to somehow stop this issue is setting delagete to nil, update object and set delagate back to self.

Is this a bug? If it isn't, how can I prevent this? Thanks

Some bug reports with same/similar issue

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12184

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4999

[iOS 9 - "attempt to delete and reload the same index path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383760/ios-9-attempt-to-delete-and-reload-the-same-index-path)

I ran both XCode6 and XCode7 versions and printed `didChangeObject` method here is the comparison

**XCode6 iOS 8.4**

```
Update New: Optional(<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) Old: Optional(<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})
```

**XCode 7b6 iOS 8.4**

```
Update New: nil Old: Optional(<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})
Insert New: Optional(<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) Old: Optional(<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})

2015-09-01 01:15:37.898 TestProg[3230:200562] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44.2/UITableView.m:1623
2015-09-01 01:15:37.900 TestProg[3230:200562] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)
```

Comment: In my current project I also use the `configureCell` method, I think I changed it because of a similar bug. Could you show your configure cell method perhaps?

Comment: it is mosty boilerplate code. I have one to many relationship. Something like below: 
   
     func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Person
      //etc
      }

Comment: Does your FRC have a sort descriptor or a predicate referring to a relationship via key path? That can sometimes lead to unexpected results.

Comment: let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
finder.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
I really started to believe that this is bug. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12184  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4999
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383760/ios-9-attempt-to-delete-and-reload-the-same-index-path

Comment: Please put your code into your question. It is not readable in the comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have tried several things and I believe this is a bug. As you can see from my log, even though I update existing record, delegate gets Insert Message. Adding conditional check at `.Insert` fixed my issue. I am not using any move operation in the table. Therefore same kind of conditional operation maybe necessary as well if you are using `.Move` My Current code is like below

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        //FIXME: iOS 9 Bug!
        if indexPath != newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
       }
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
       tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        // self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)

    case .Move:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

I have tried to update single record, multiple records and I haven't seen any crashes yet so far. I am using

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

method but

```
self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
```

also worked during my tests.

Comment: I only tested with Xcode 7.0 Beta 6, GM, and Xcode 7.0 Release build.

Comment: Okay, it helped - for .Insert case I am checking if indexPath is nil, which should be.

Do you have any idea why this is happening? I.e. CoreData update causes two events to happen.

Comment: As far as I heard it is due to bug in swift. So if one of the enum raw value is 0 and if it is not part of enum we check, swift calls first selector which is Insert. I heard that it is being fixed in in Xcode 7.1.1 but I haven't tested by myself.

Comment: omg, @Meanteacher is totally right, the enum is totally busted. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/29866#29866

Comment: So, it has been a couple of years. For .Update, is it now recommended to use reloadRowsAtIndexPaths or configureCell?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be happening to me when running on Sim/Device < iOS9 using Xcode 7 beta 6:

```
2015-09-01 11:39:05.683 Diabetes Pal[15038:245613] *** Assertion failure in 
-[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44.2/UITableView.m:1623
2015-09-01 11:39:14.954 Diabetes Pal[15038:245613] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  
An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to 
-controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)
Diabetes Pal(15038,0x33291d4) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1048576) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region securely
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

A possible workaround is to not animate the changes (until this is fixed):

```
//MARK: - fetched results controller delegate

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    let ios9 = NSOperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 9, minorVersion: 0, patchVersion: 0)
    if NSProcessInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion(ios9) {
        tableView?.beginUpdates()
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {        
    let ios9 = NSOperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 9, minorVersion: 0, patchVersion: 0)
    if NSProcessInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion(ios9) == false {
        return
    } //[... rest of delegate implementation ...]
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    let ios9 = NSOperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 9, minorVersion: 0, patchVersion: 0)
    if NSProcessInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion(ios9) == false {
        return
    }//[... rest of delegate implementation ...] 
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    let ios9 = NSOperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 9, minorVersion: 0, patchVersion: 0)
    if NSProcessInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion(ios9) == false {
        tableView?.reloadData()
        return
    }
    tableView?.endUpdates()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not see this problem any more when I build upon SDK 9.1. It seems the bug have been fixed. You can try it.