# Core Data sends false NSFetchedResultsContoller .Insert signal

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Saving a managed object, it is not created, but an existing changed. Despite `NSFetchedResultsController` send an `.Insert` signal, any idea why it happens?

Strange that it happens only in Xcode 7, after code conversion to Swift 2.0.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32336934/3985749) might be relevant?

Comment: Your question is fairly vague with no code details.  Can you isolate this in a test case?  If you can't then it is an issue in your code. If you can, post the sample so people can help.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I have exactly the problem like the linked question before, and the suggested trick worked for me, this is an apple bug, hopefully with Xcode 7.1 it will be fixed