# "Better" way to write equality for optionals

Tags: swift

I am trying to find a better way to test equality. What I dislike is the part with profileImage.

Is there a nicer way to write it?

```
class CustomObject : NSObject , NSCoding {
    var pattern : String
    var name : String
    var id : String
    var profilePicture : NSImage?

    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if let other = object as? CustomObject {
            if (id == other.id &&
                name == other.name &&
                pattern == other.pattern) {
                    if (profilePicture == nil && other.profilePicture == nil) {
                        return true
                    } else {
                        return profilePicture!.isEqual(other.profilePicture)
                    }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Just `profilePicture == other.profilePicture` should work, compare  [how to compare two optional NSArrays in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307242/how-to-compare-two-optional-nsarrays-in-swift).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement nearly the same as you have shown, my best recommendation is using `==` operator. (Not `===`, don't be confused.)

`==` has an overload for Optionals with this signature: (in Swift 2)

```
@warn_unused_result
public func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

And its detailed behaviour is as follows:

(1) if lhs == nil && rhs == nil, return true

(2) if lhs == nil && rhs != nil, return false

(3) if lhs != nil && rhs == nil, return false

(4) if lhs != nil && rhs != nil, return (lhs! == rhs!)

And in case #4, non-Optional version of `==` operator for two NSObject arguments, just calls `isEqual:` method internally.

So, `CustomObject.isEqual(_:)` can be written as something like this:

```
override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if let other = object as? CustomObject {
        return id == other.id &&
            name == other.name &&
            pattern == other.pattern &&
            profilePicture == other.profilePicture
    }
    return false
}
```

(Assuming your `NSImage.isEqual(_:)` works as expected.)

---

By the way, your original code may crash in a certain condition.

```
                if (profilePicture == nil && other.profilePicture == nil) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return profilePicture!.isEqual(other.profilePicture)
                }
```

When profilePicture == nil && other.profilePicture != nil, the control goes through to the `else` part and `profilePicture!` will crash.

Comment: Thanks, did not cover that by unit test. +1